# Indent and alignment not working in office-js-in-word WordApi 1.2

Tags: c#, office-js, add-in, word-addins

I am trying to add indent & alignment in paragraphs of the document. It is working for me when I have used office.js "WordApi 1.3" but I need to implement in the office.js "WordApi 1.1 or WordApi 1.2".

I am using Word 2016 MSO (Build number:- Word 2016 MSO(16.0.4738.1000)32-bit)

Below the code i have tryied using WordApi 1.2:-

```cs
context.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst().leftIndent = 75; 
context.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst().alignment = "Centered";
```

Getting below error:- 
{"description":"InvalidArgument","name":"RichApi.Error","code":"InvalidArgument","traceMessages":[],"innerError":null,"debugInfo":{"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"InvalidArgument","errorLocation":""},"stack":"InvalidArgument: InvalidArgument\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:288131)\n   at T (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:221040)\n   at x (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:221126)\n   at t (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:220934)\n   at l (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:24:219441)"}

Any example to achieve this?

Many thanks..!!!

Comment: Yes question code i have used from official site. find below url:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#leftindent. Facing issue in Build number:- Word 2016 MSO(16.0.4738.1000)32-bit

Comment: Thank you for completing the information. I'm not able to test for you, as I don't have the static Office 2016 version to test on. @RickKirkham might be able to provide more information...